# error: websocket.js:84 WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:5000/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket' failed:

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, websocket

I am building a realtime chat application using **reactJs**, **node** and **socket.io** . But i am getting the error that **websocket connection has failed**. This is the error which i am getting  in the console `websocket.js:84 WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:5000/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket' failed:`

This is **client** side code

```js
   
let socket;

const Chat = ({ location }) => {
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const { name, room } = queryString.parse(location.search);
    socket = io(ENDPOINT, { transports: ['websocket'] })
    setName(name);
    setRoom(room);

    socket.emit('join', { name, room }, () => {

    })
    return () => {
      socket.emit('disconnect');

      socket.off();
    }
  
  }, [ENDPOINT, location.search])

  useEffect(() => {
    socket.on('message', (message) => {
      setMessages([...messages, message]);
    })
  }, [messages]);


  const sendMessage = (event) => {
    event.preventDefaut();
    if (message) {
      socket.emit('sendMessage', message, () => setMessage(''));
    }
  }
  console.log(message, messages);
  return (
    <div className="outerContainer">
      <div className="container" >
        <input value={message} onChange={(event) => setMessage(event.target.value)} onKeyPress={event => event.key === 'Enter' ? sendMessage(event) : null} />
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Chat;
```

and this is server side code

```js
const { addUsers, removeUser, getUser, getUsersInRoom } = require('./users')

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000

const router = require('./router');

const app = express();

const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = socketio(server);

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  socket.on('join', ({ name, room }, callback) => {

    const { error, user } = addUsers({ id: socket.id, name, room });

    if (error) return callback(error);

    socket.emit('message', { user: 'admin', text: `${user.name} , welcome to room ${user.room}` });
    socket.broadcast.to(user.room).emit('message', { user: 'admin', text: `${user.name} has joined` });

    socket.join(user.room);

    callback();
  })

  socket.on('sendMessage', (message, callback) => {
    const user = getUser(socket.id);

    io.to(user.room).emit('message', { user: user.name, text: message });

    callback();
  })

  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    console.log("user have left");
  })
})
```

I tried to solve this but could not find anything in official documentaion.
How to fix this issue?

Comment: How did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

server side. in *index.js file* use check(?) `(user?.room)`

```
io.to(user?.room).emit('message', { user: user.name, text: message });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think adding headers to the request might solve the issue. I read it in the socket.io documentation. I hope this would help your issue. Let me know how it goes.
Example:

```
socket = io(ENDPOINT, {  
        cors: {
        origin: "http://localhost:5000",
        credentials: true
      },transports : ['websocket'] });
```